# Cannot expose Jenkins externally

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, jenkins

I'm hosting jenkins on windows (historical reasons)
Just updated it from **1.620** to **2.62**

Everything works as expected, except the tiny details that I cannot access it anymore.
Only accessing it from host works.

I found numerous posts about it and they all suggested changing startup params to set:

```
--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0
```

or

```
--httpListenAddress=HOST
```

I've tried both solutions, same result.
Jenkins works when accessed from the host by:

- 127.0.0.1
- 10.0.1.11 (internal ip)
- x.x.x.x (external ip)
- HOST

but doesn't work when accessed from any other machine.

I've checked firewall and azure settings. Other service (nexus:8081) is accessible as expected. Changing port to 8080 didn't help.

that's `jenkins.xml`

```
<service>
  <id>jenkins</id>
  <name>Jenkins</name>
  <description>This service runs Jenkins continuous integration system.            
</description>
  <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>
  <env name="HTTP_HOST" value="HOST.cloudapp.net"/>
  <executable>%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=80 --httpListenAddress="%HTTP_HOST%" --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
  <logmode>rotate</logmode>
  <onfailure action="restart" />
</service>
```

that's jenkins log

```
INFO: Started w.@1750fbeb{/,file:///E:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{E:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war}
May 25, 2017 2:17:51 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@7ae0a9ec{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{HOST.cloudapp.net:80}
May 25, 2017 2:17:51 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: Started @4534ms
May 25, 2017 2:17:51 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v4.0 running: controlPort=disabled
May 25, 2017 2:17:54 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
May 25, 2017 2:17:55 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
(removed few lines about ruby failing)
INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
May 25, 2017 2:18:04 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading plugin ruby-runtime v0.12 (ruby-runtime)
May 25, 2017 2:18:40 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

when `httpListenAddress` was `0.0.0.0` log was:

```
INFO: Started ServerConnector@7ae0a9ec{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:80}
```

Comment: Did you also try to use empty parameter for `httpListenAddress`, so e.g. something like`--httpListenAddress=` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so turns out this question has nothing to do with Jenkins. So I apologize anyone you tried answering.
(Correct setting is either using the default value for `httpListenAddress` or setting it to `--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0`)

It was windows firewall.
For old jenkis - **1.620** firewall had a rule for **Java 6** and port 80. New jenkins is using **Java 8** which was blocked.

Changing firewall rules fixed the problem.

Comment: 'New-NetFirewallRule' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody trying to install Jenkins on Windows in a PowerShell script, this is how to tell the firewall to open the port:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Name jenkins -DisplayName 'Jenkins' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 8080
```